# NextJS Data Fetching using accessToken from next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have setup next-auth with CustomCredentials and everything is working smooth i get the access token from the backend, store it and everything is smooth. Later i need to use this token as a Authorization header and there is where i hit the wall. This is my code so far:

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { NextApiRequest } from 'next';

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3004/api/auth/password';

enum API_ERRORS {
  UPDATE_PASSWORD = 'Failed to update password'
}

const getAccessToken = async (req: NextApiRequest) => {
  const session = (await getSession({ req })) as any;
  return session?.accessToken;
};

export const updatePasswordApi = async (data: {
  oldPassword: string;
  newPassword: string;
}) => {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken(); // how to pass req?

  const response = await fetch(baseUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer {accessToken}`
    }
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(API_ERRORS.UPDATE_PASSWORD);
  }

  return response.json();
};
```

I'm really not sure maybe i miss some big piece but how to pass the header, everywhere where i check examples nobody is passing custom header or whatsoever really confused. If someone knows please kindly share